# How can I get a list of all messages in my gmail account in linux command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gmail, wget, curl

How can I get a list of all messages in my gmail account in linux command line?
Ideally I would want to see something similar to:

```
from:sender1@domain.com to:me@gmail.com Date:11/22/33 subj:Foo1
from:sender2@domain.com to:me@gmail.com Date:11/22/33 subj:Foo2
```

Not necessary with words from, to etc or certain order.
Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing you want this to be a done repeatedly? Sort of like an update?

Comment: Most likely solution would entail:

(1) Use of a commandline browser like `lynx` 

(2) Either a post command or Gmail API (if you use the email with Google Apps)

(3) The use of the html-based UI page for your inbox: `http://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html` with a parameter like `-dump` in lynx to move it to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) with a shell script [found here](http://www.shellperson.net/quickly-check-gmail-with-bash/).

This will write to the screen if you have email or not.

Just change the `USERNAME` & `PASSWORD` entries to your own.

```
#!/bin/bash
## Quickly checks if I have new gmail

echo -e "Checking for new messages... \c"

atomlines=`wget -T 3 -t 1 -q --secure-protocol=TLSv1 \
 --no-check-certificate \
 --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD \
 https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom -O - \
 | wc -l`

echo -e "\r\c"

[ $atomlines -gt "8" ] \
 && echo -e " You have new gmail.  \c" \
 || echo -e " No new gmail.  \c"
```